# Where is chrome extension's 'chrome.storage.local' data saved?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I can find the previous localStorage api data in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage` directory. I see that these are sqlite files which I can browse with sqlite3.

However, I'm moving from localStorage api to `chrome.storage` api and saving the information with `chrome.storage.local` method.

Now, how and where are these files are bing saved in my file system? I can't seem to find any information regarding this in their [doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Extension Settings/EXTENSIONID HERE`

Comment: I didn't see any folder named 'Local Extension Settings' in the 'Default' folder Rob. :(
My chrome version is Version 28.0.1500.71

Comment: The data is stored in almost plain text. Just grep for saved data to locate the directory.

Comment: @RobW I'm using Chrome 69 and even though the path you provided exists, it's not possible to grep for the data. Maybe Google has improved their security.

Comment: @RobW never mind, I was able to find the data after shutting down Chrome. Looks like Chrome puts a lock on these files when it's currently running.

Answer (score 8):

For Windows, you can find different data related to your extension [extension_id] at these places

C:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings\[extension_id]

C:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sync Extension Settings\[extension_id]

C:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\chrome-extension_[extension_id]

want to checkout chrome.storage data

- open developer tools pointing your background page
- type command

  **chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function (data) { console.info(data) });**

  or

  **chrome.storage.local.get(null, function (data) { console.info(data) });**

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox which now use the same format as Chrome for addon they are saved here:

C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\x5jztslz.default\browser-extension-data\

Comment: [not anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65448110/where-are-the-data-for-extension-storage-of-a-firefox-extension-stored-in/71468709#71468709)