# Where I can find GM_xmlhttpRequest xhr console logs

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

I have a little userscript running on Tampermonkey in Firefox (chrome has the same behavior)

The xhr logs of these requests doesn't appear in the console or network analysis.

Because it is a cors request from https to a http service, we have to use `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` and cannot use `fetch()` or normal `XmlHttpRequest`

The request report sometimes an error and sometimes not, so the information would be very helpful to solve our issue.
My question is, where I can find these logs, or how can I turn it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GM_xmlhttpRequest()` is usually run from the background script of the userscript manager.

As mentioned in the following topic, you can open the relative console and check the Network tab.

> [Can't get Firefox extension logs to show up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70819429/3529456)
>
> Firefox console has been divided into different areas. The result of
> `console.log()` can be viewed in the relative area.
>
> - Multiprocess Browser Console *Ctrl+Shift+J*      Mostly logs by Firefox itself
> - Web Developer Tools *Ctrl+Shift+I* or *F12*     Logs by Tab/Webpage and Content scripts of addons
> - Extension Toolbox *about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox ➜ XYZaddon ➜ Inspect*     Logs by background scripts of XYZaddon